# Not able to switch to directory using CD command in batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, command, cd

As i am getting the directortry path dynamically, but while switching it using CD it gets the default path of the script file where it is placed:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%i in ("%~dp0..\Project\abc") do set "folder=%%~fi"
echo !folder!
for %%i in ("%~dp0..\Dependencies\Apache\bin") do set "Apache=%%~fi"
echo !Apache!
CD !Apache! //This does not change the directory
echo %~dp0
httpd -k start -c "DocumentRoot !folder!"
pause
```

Comment: Any errormessages? Btw: `%~dp0` *always* gives you the drive/path of your batchfile. It won't change. Use `echo %cd%` instead. Also you might want to add the  `/d` switch to the `cd` command. (see `cd /?`)

Comment: Error Message:The system cannot find the path specified. I have also tried with cd /d and %cd% but still getting the same error.

Comment: if the path doesn't exist, then no switch can help you. Verify `%Apache%` and `%folder%`.